# Set custom UISegmentedControl height

Tags: swift, uikit, uisegmentedcontrol

I am trying to set the height of the segmented control to be higher than the default. I am not too familiar with UIKit so I am having a hard time getting it to work. I am using the picker in SwiftUI via a representable. Here is my code...

```
struct SegmentedControl: UIViewRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewType = UISegmentedControl
    
    var items: [String]
    @Binding var selectedSegmentIndex: Int
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UISegmentedControl {
        let segmentedControl = UISegmentedControl(items: items)
        
        
        segmentedControl.frame.size.height = 50.0

        
        segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = selectedSegmentIndex
        segmentedControl.addTarget(context.coordinator, action: #selector(Coordinator.valueChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
        let titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
        UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(titleTextAttributes, for: .selected)
        UISegmentedControl.appearance().selectedSegmentTintColor = .systemBlue
        
        
        
        return segmentedControl
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UISegmentedControl, context: Context) {
        uiView.selectedSegmentIndex = selectedSegmentIndex
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject {
        var control: SegmentedControl
        
        init(_ control: SegmentedControl) {
            self.control = control
        }
        
        @objc func valueChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
            control.selectedSegmentIndex = sender.selectedSegmentIndex
        }
    }
}
```

Here is where I show the picker representable in SwiftUI

```
struct TestingView: View {
    
    enum ProfileSection : String, CaseIterable {
        case tweets = "Tweets"
        case media = "Media"
        case likes = "Likes"
    }
    
    @State var segmentationSelection : ProfileSection = .tweets
    
    var body: some View {
        SegmentedControl(items: ProfileSection.allCases.map { $0.rawValue }, selectedSegmentIndex: Binding(
            get: { self.segmentationSelection.rawValue.hashValue },
            set: { newIndex in
                if let newSelection = ProfileSection.allCases.first(where: { $0.rawValue.hashValue == newIndex }) {
                    self.segmentationSelection = newSelection
                }
            }
        ))
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use SwiftUI `Picker` with a segmented picker style?

Comment: SwiftUI's picker has little to no customization options. I am looking to have a selected color of blue and customize the height.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70693145/how-to-set-height-of-segmented-controller-in-swiftui for a possible solution.